# SUMO traci.simulation.findroute.m

Tags: sumo

I am using TraCI function: traci.simulation.findroute.m to find a route for the vehicle. The documentation of the function says that it will find the route which uses shortest travel time. I am wondering, if the function computes the travel time only using the travel distance and speed, or the function also take the transportation condition (like the traffic flow) into consideration.
Hope someone could help me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure which values TraCI takes into account when routing. The according parameter is the so-called routing mode (I don't know whether it is part of the matlab interface already). More details can be found here: https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Simulation/Routing.html#travel-time_values_for_routing

Answer (score -1):

SUMO uses the algorithms `Djikstra or A*` to compute the **shortest or the fastest route** when provided with a set of `demand definitions` and/or `edge-weights` (check [DUAROUTER](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/DUAROUTER.html)).

When using `A*`, the parameter `euclidean distance/maximum vehicle speed` is computed to design the routes.

To take the current traffic conditions into account, `DUAROUTER` needs to be iteratively called in conjunction with current SUMO simulation step, a job that is performed using the tool [`duaIterate.py`](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Demand/Dynamic_User_Assignment.html#iterative_assignment_dynamic_user_equilibrium)

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct. Routing in TraCI is different from what duarouter does.